# Spring Integration - File Inbound Channel Adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying sample program with file - inbound channel Adapter. I just want to read the file using adapter and pass it to the transformer to convert into Map and finally pass it to Service Activator to print the map.

When i run the program it is reaching transformer from Adapter but it is not reaching the Service Activator at all.

As i have used the Inbound Channel Adapter here, i have not used Gateway as an entry point. Is this something wrong?

```
@Configuration
public class SpringIntegrationAdapterConfig {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SpringIntegrationAdapterConfig.class);

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fileInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageResource(){
    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setDirectory(new File("C:\\Rajashree\\work\\test"));
    source.setFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("Sample.csv"));

    log.info("Reading file using File Adapter");

    return source;
}
}

@Component
public class FileService {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FileService.class);

@Transformer(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel", outputChannel =  "mappingChannel")
public List<Map<String, String>> readFile(File file){
    log.info(file.getName());

    List<Map<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader();

    try(CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(new FileReader(file), csvFormat)){
        parser.getRecords().stream().map(e ->    dataList.add(e.toMap())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        log.info(dataList);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("File read Error : " + e);
    }

    return dataList;
  }
 }


 @Component
 public class MappingTransformer {

     @Transformer(inputChannel = "mappingChannel", outputChannel =   "printChannel")
     public List<Map<String, String>> mapFields(List<Map<String, String>> dataList){
      System.out.println("File mapped :: " + dataList );
      return dataList;
     }
}

  @MessageEndpoint
  public class printService{

   @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="printChannel", outputChannel=  "outputChannel")
   public void print(List<Map<String, String>> dataList){
       System.out.println("Message Printed");
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is something interesting in logs. Looks like your transformer throws error. That's why you can't reach the next component.

In addition you can switch on `DEBUG` for the `org.springframework.integration` category and investigate logs how your messages travel.

Comment: Transformer is working fine. I loaded the file using normal method and invoked transformer through gateway. The whole flow works fine. But i wanted to load the file using File Adapter and its not working.

Comment: Your "but" should be confirmed with logs and stack state, please.

Comment: Let me found out... Thank you